# Image Uploading Android Php Response is Null Image is not uploded

Tags: php, android

I have many try to uploading the image in android php but some response is null problem...

Image uploading android response is null...plz provided any idea to solve image uploading....

php side code is perfectly uploded image successfully but android side not work this code...

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    // Activity request codes
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    // directory name to store captured images and videos
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Hello Camera";

    private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video

    private ImageView imgPreview;
    private Button btnCapturePicture, btn_upload_image;
    static File mediaFile;
    Bitmap rotatedBMP=null;
    String selectedImagePath,
            ServerUploadPath = "http://192.168.43.195/uploadservices/Images/"
                    + "", str_response;
    String TAG = "Final Image";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            setid();
            setevent();



        }

//        // Checking camera availability
       if (!isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // will close the app if the device does't have camera
            finish();
        }
    }

private void setevent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_upload_image.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void setid() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        btnCapturePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_select);
        btn_upload_image = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_upload);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_select:
                // capture picture
                CameraAndGallaryCapture();

                break;
            case R.id.btn_upload:
                /*StaticData.staimage = rotatedBMP;
                Intent catintent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Catagories.class);
                startActivity(catintent);*/
                new UploadTask().execute(rotatedBMP);

            default:
                break;
        }
    }





    private void CameraAndGallaryCapture() {
        final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery",
                "Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    captureImage();
                } else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                    takePhotoGallery();
                } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }

        });
        builder.show();
    }

    private void takePhotoGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                SELECT_PICTURE);
    }

    /**
     * Checking device has camera hardware or not
     * */
    private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Capturing Camera Image will lauch camera app requrest image capture
     */
    private void captureImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /*
     * Creating file uri to store image/video
     */
    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /*
     * returning image / video
     */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File( Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        Log.e("path", "media file:-" + mediaFile);
        return mediaFile;
    }

    /*
     * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
     * app
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // save file url in bundle as it will be null on scren orientation
        // changes
        outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // get the file url
        fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
    }

    /**
     * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                Log.d("select pah", "path" + selectedImagePath);
                previewCapturedImage();
            }

        }
        // if the result is capturing Image
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // successfully captured the image
                // display it in image view
                selectedImagePath = mediaFile.toString();
                previewCapturedImage();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }

    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    /*
     * Display image from a path to ImageView
     */
    private void previewCapturedImage() {
        try {

            int targetW = 380;
            int targetH = 800;
            Log.d("Get w", "width" + targetW);
            Log.d("Get H", "height" + targetH);
            // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, bmOptions);
            int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
            int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

            // Determine how much to scale down the image
            int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);

            // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor << 1;
            bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath,
                    bmOptions);

            Matrix mtx = new Matrix();

            try {

                File imageFile = new File(selectedImagePath);

                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                        imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                        ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                Log.e("Orintation", "  :-" + orientation);
                switch (orientation) {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:

                        mtx.postRotate(270);
                        rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                                bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mtx, true);
                        if (rotatedBMP != bitmap)
                            bitmap.recycle();
                        imgPreview.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);

                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:

                        mtx.postRotate(180);
                        rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                                bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mtx, true);
                        if (rotatedBMP != bitmap)
                            bitmap.recycle();
                        imgPreview.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:

                        mtx.postRotate(90);
                        rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                                bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mtx, true);
                        if (rotatedBMP != bitmap)
                            bitmap.recycle();
                        imgPreview.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:

                        mtx.postRotate(0);
                        rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                                bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mtx, true);
                        if (rotatedBMP != bitmap)
                            bitmap.recycle();
                        imgPreview.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);
                        break;
                    default:
                        mtx.postRotate(0);
                        rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                                bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mtx, true);
                        if (rotatedBMP != bitmap)
                            bitmap.recycle();
                        imgPreview.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);
                        // img_profilepic.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        // .decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath));

                }

                Log.i("RotateImage", "Exit orientation: " + orientation);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



 private class UploadTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Dialog.setMessage("Uploading Image...");
            Dialog.setCancelable(false);
            Dialog.show();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
            if (bitmaps[0] == null)
                return null;
            setProgress(0);

            Bitmap bitmap = bitmaps[0];
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); // convert
            // Bitmap
            // to
            // ByteArrayOutputStream
            // Bitmap
            // to
            // ByteArrayOutputStream
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray()); // convert
            // ByteArrayOutputStream
            // to
            // ByteArrayInputStream

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            try {
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://192.168.43.195/uploadservices/upload.php");
                // // server
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost1 = new HttpPost(ServerUploadPath); // server

                MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
                //reqEntity.addPart("email", "vishal.sojitra259@Gmail.com");
                reqEntity.addPart("uploaded_file", System.currentTimeMillis()
                        + ".jpg", in);

                httppost1.setEntity(reqEntity);

                Log.i(TAG, "request " + httppost1.getRequestLine());
                HttpResponse response = null;
                try {
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost1);
                    str_response = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {

                    if (response != null)
                        Log.d(TAG, "response "
                                + response.getStatusLine().toString());

                } finally {

                }
            } finally {

            }

            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (stream != null) {
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Dialog.dismiss();
            Log.e("Response is", "..." + str_response);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload Complete....",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }


}
```

***PHP code :

upload.php***

```
<?php


    $image_name = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]; 
    $tmp_arr = explode(".",$image_name);
    $img_extn = end($tmp_arr);
    $new_image_name = 'image_'. uniqid() .'.'.$img_extn;    
    $flag=0;                 
    if (file_exists("Images/".$new_image_name))
    {
       $dataObj->ResponseMessage("2","already exists.","False");
    }
    else
    {   

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"],"Images/". $new_image_name);
        $flag = 1;
        $static_url = "http://http://192.168.1.103/ppp/sharechat/Images/".$new_image_name;

        echo "file insert ";

    }   
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would help you

```
public class PhotoUploader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


        private String photoNameInServer;
        private static final int PHOTO_QUALITY = 70;
        private Photo photoToBeUploaded;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


                //Uploading Image
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(params[0]); //ImagePath

                //Hey Client, I want to post few photos, Let's bring it.
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();

                //Passing data in POST
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://example.com/post.php"); //URL

                //This is multipart data (file)
                MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, PHOTO_QUALITY, bos);
                byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

                entity.addPart("photo", new ByteArrayBody(data, "image/jpeg", photoNameInServer));
                post.setEntity(entity);

                try {
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post, context);

                    finalResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                    Log.d("X", "Final Response:" + finalResponse);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            return finalResponse;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }
    }
```

then you could upload image by

```
new PhotoUploader().execute("file-path");
```

and don't forget to add the `httpmime-4.1.3` library.

Comment: @PrAfulPArmar 10months!! :D

Comment: Sorry bro.i will try this code before 10 month its worked.but i will open account today...thanksss

Comment: @PrAfulPArmar It's ok, i just said. :)